# Spring Boot, Freemarker, MVC Unit Tests, Csrf

Tags: c#, unit-testing, spring-boot, csrf, freemarker

Im using Freemarker with Spring Boot and do mvc unit tests. In my freemarker template I have a hidden input field for the csrf token like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Then I also have a mvc unit test :

```
        @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MvcTests {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext ctx;

    MockMvc mvc;

    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mvc = webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
        httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    }


    @Test
    public void testInValidVoucherNumber() throws Exception {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(new MockHttpServletRequest());
        mvc.perform(post("/voucher/claim")
                .sessionAttr("_csrf.parameterName", "_csrf")
                .sessionAttr("_csrf.token", csrfToken.getToken())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .param("code", "ABC")
                .param("_csrf", csrfToken.getToken()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("claim-voucher"))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Code is invalid")));
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test I get the following freemarker error:

```
    testInValidVoucherNumber(MvcTests)  Time elapsed: 0.904 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> _csrf  [in template "claim-voucher.ftl" at line 25, column 34]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${_csrf.parameterName}  [in template "claim-voucher.ftl" at line 25, column 32]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "layout.ftl" in macro "basic" at line 16, column 9]
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/voucher/claim", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkVoucherCode(@Valid ClaimVoucherForm claimVoucherForm, Model model)  {
    //Business logic
}
```

It seems like freemarker does not have access to the csrf parameterName and csrf token. Is there a way to include the csrf information without changing the controller or is there a problem with the unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.sessionAttr("_csrf.parameterName", "_csrf")
.sessionAttr("_csrf.token", csrfToken.getToken())
```

Try:

```
.sessionAttr("_csrf", csrfToken)
```

When you write `${_csrf.parameterName}`, FreeMarker looks for the field "parameterName" on the model variable "_csrf". Not for the model variable "_csrf.parameterName".

That said, it's weird that you have to add those parameters as session attributes in your test. Shouldn't Spring Security's CsrfFilter do that for you?

Comment: It is weird, I used thymeleaf previously and I did not have to add the csrf tokens to the html, then I switched to Freemarker because thymeleaf gave me issues. Since then I had to add the csrf tags or I would get a error when posting the form to the server.

Comment: That's because Spring's JSP/Thymeleaf form tags automatically add hidden fields for you: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6062e15572eefa73954a69c109cc90f068486065/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.java#L484-L512 and https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/blob/2e752f705e7be87ef7d077d90ff822d248d9033b/thymeleaf-spring4/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/spring4/processor/attr/SpringActionAttrProcessor.java#L96-L122 .

Answer (score 1):

Session attributes are made available in the model with a `Session.` prefix. Your template needs to be updated to something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${Session._csrf.parameterName}" value="${Session._csrf.token}"/>
```

You're also configuring the session attributes incorrectly in your test. `_csrf.token` means that Freemarker will look for an object named `_csrf` and then look for an attribute named `token` on that object. You need to assign a session attribute named `_csrf` that contains `parameterName` and `token`:

```java
Map<String, Object> csrf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
csrf.put("parameterName", "_csrf");
csrf.put("token",  csrfToken.getToken());
mvc.perform(post("/voucher/claim")
            .sessionAttr("_csrf", csrf)
```

Comment: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> Session._csrf  [in template "claim-voucher.ftl" at line 31, column 34]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue using

```
@Import({CsrfFilter.class, HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.class})
```

On top of my test class and without using any `.sessionAttr()` calls.